# Issue with value conversion in iOS using NSUInteger and NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsuinteger

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` which holds several items in a key/value pairing.  I have stored strings with a key and retrieved them without issue, however, when I store a value of type `NSUInteger` and try to fetch that back from the dictionary I end up with a really large value.

The first part of my if statement I check to see if the value I am looking for is not null or greater than zero.  I am trying to basically hold a score or value in the dictionary that I can access so I can add to or take away from.

As you can see in the else statement I have two `NSLog` statements, this is where I see the difference in the value.  The first `NSLog` statement displays a value of 100, as I would expect from clicking my 'Happy' button.  However, once the value is retrieved back from the dictionary the currentTotal is 109709424.  I am sure this has something to do with the format specifier I am using in the conversion of this integer value to a string.  I tried storing this value, currentTotal, as an int or NSUInteger in my dictionary under the key "Total" but the conversion from a non objective-c type object to an 'id' is disallowed in ARC so I am stuck.

```
NSUInteger currentTotal = 0;
NSUInteger happinessValue = 100;
NSUInteger sadnessValue = 20; 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if ([appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"] != nil || [appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"] > 0) {

        currentTotal = (int)[appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"];

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Happy"]) {
            [segue.destinationViewController setHappiness:(int)happinessValue :segue.identifier];
            currentTotal = add(currentTotal, happinessValue);

            [appDelegate.data setObject:(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Value: %i", happinessValue] forKey:@"Value"];
        } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Sad"]) {
            [segue.destinationViewController setHappiness:(int)sadnessValue :segue.identifier];
            currentTotal -= [segue.destinationViewController setTotalValue:happinessValue];
            [appDelegate.data setObject:(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Value: %i", sadnessValue] forKey:@"Value"];
        }
    }
    else {

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Happy"]) {
            [segue.destinationViewController setHappiness:(int)happinessValue :segue.identifier];
            NSLog(@"Old value ELSE: %i", currentTotal);
            currentTotal = [segue.destinationViewController setTotalValue:happinessValue];
            NSLog(@"New value ELSE: %i", currentTotal);
            [appDelegate.data setObject:(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Value: %i", happinessValue] forKey:@"Value"];
        } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Sad"]) {
            [segue.destinationViewController setHappiness:(int)sadnessValue :segue.identifier];
            currentTotal = [segue.destinationViewController setTotalValue:happinessValue];
            [appDelegate.data setObject:(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Value: %i", sadnessValue] forKey:@"Value"];
        }

        NSLog(@"Current Total: %i", currentTotal);
        [appDelegate.data setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentTotal] forKey:@"Total"];
        NSLog(@"Total stored: %i", (int)[appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem:

```
currentTotal = (int)[appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"];
```

`-valueForKey:` returns a pointer to an Objective-C object, not an `int`, so you cannot cast it to an `int` and expect anything useful to happen. If it is an `NSNumber`, then you need to do something like this:

```
currentTotal = [[appDelegate.data valueForKey:@"Total"] intValue];
```

See [the docs on `NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.